# Can't install kernel 4.20 because of compatibility issue with Nvidia driver 410.78

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I tried to manually install the 4.20 Kernel (using instructions from: https://www.tecmint.com/upgrade-kernel-in-ubuntu/ ) but I got a compatibililty error with the Nvidia driver 410.78.

It told me to check: `/var/lib/dkms/nvidia/410.78/build/make.log` ; there I can see things like:

```
DKMS make.log for nvidia-410.78 for kernel 4.20.0-042000-generic (x86_64)
Thu Jan 10 07:44:29 +13 2019
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.20.0-042000-generic'
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
```

Do you have any suggestions? Maybe I can open a ticket somewhere? What caused this error?

Thanks

Comment: @user68186 Maybe it's in development but I need it to fix issues with my Asus RoG laptop (issues that are present in the stable ones). I know as a fact newer versions solved issues for others with my hardware. Can you be more specific which kernel versions are considered supported in at least a stable version of Ubuntu? I could try the latest among those and see if it fixes my issues. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks @user68186 I have 18.04 LTS and the latest kernel for it is 4.15 right now. Will try with 4.18.

Comment: It worked with 4.18 and with those kernel install instructions.

Comment: Once 18.04.2 is released you may want to upgrade to the kernel 4.18 provided via the usual system. This will make sure that the kernel is kept up to date as new bugs and vulnerabilities are squashed in the kernel.

Comment: You asked about supported kernels, refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Support , and you'll note @user68186 is correct re: HWE kernels.  Yes Canonical/Ubuntu do package other kernels for testing purposes, but they are used for testing, and usually abandoned pretty quickly after QA-tests complete unless adopted and thus patches & security-updates are not made for them. These unsupported kernels may be safe if you machine is off-line, but shouldn't be used otherwise (except for testing).

Answer (score 0):

echo >&2 "         Run '`make oldconfig && make prepare`' on kernel src to fix it.";  \

Comment: Can you be more specific and how that integrates with the kernel install instructions at the URL I was talking about?

Answer (score 0):

nvidia-dkms-415 package seems compatible with 4.20 kernel. If there isn't a specific reason for you to stick to 410, I suggest you upgrade the driver

Answer (score 0):

How did you install the driver? You should do so via your package manager.

Then, I suggest using the [Ukuu kernel update utility](https://github.com/teejee2008/ukuu) if you need to install a more updated kernel than what Ubuntu provides by default (currently has `4.20` and `5.0-rc2` listed as options, among others).